# How to replicate variables to new Linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

Is there any way to make a replica of current shell with all environment variables set in that particular shell?

Consider a shell where I've initialized variables `var1`, `var2` and `var3`. Ideally the variable values will not be known to a new shell, e.g. a shell in a separate (fresh) tab in my terminal emulator. I would like to make a replica of the current shell with respect to the variables set there. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes exactly ! By new tab what I meant is new (Shell -> New tab) from `iTerm` which I use..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's only about variables in Bash (the question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)), [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/277969/693277) is a good starting point:

> You can see all variables with the `declare` builtin.
>
> ```
> declare -p
> ```
>
> If you're only interested in environment variables, use
>
> ```
> declare -xp
> ```
>
> Run `help declare` to see what the other options are.

The output has just the right syntax to be sourced, so the following solution emerges:

1. In the source Bash session run

   ```
   declare -p > ~/some_file
   ```
2. In the target Bash session run

   ```
   . ~/some_file 2>/dev/null
   ```

Notes:

- Some variables (like `PPID`, or those marked with `declare -r`) are readonly and you would get few warnings if you tried to set them in the target session without `2>/dev/null`. This redirection is there only to suppress such warnings. Variables that were readonly in the target session, will be left intact.
- Almost any variable that existed in the target session and in the file, will be overwritten with the value from the file. Exceptions are:

  - variables already marked as readonly in the target shell;
  - variables like `GROUPS` or `RANDOM` that are special (see `man 1 bash` for details); as far as I know `declare -p` treats them differently so they stay special in the target shell.
- Any variable that existed in the target session but not in the file, will be left intact.

  To get rid of (almost) as many "old" variables in the target shell as you can, use this command before sourcing the file:

  ```
  exec env -i bash --noprofile --norc
  ```

  It starts `bash` which reads neither startup nor initialization files (`--noprofile --norc`) in an empty environment (`env -i`). Furthermore the new `bash` replaces the current shell (`exec`) so the two processes don't stack unnecessarily (the premise is the current target shell is expendable anyway).

  In fact you can start a new `bash` and make it source the file in one command:

  ```
  exec env -i bash --noprofile --rcfile ~/some_file
  ```

So in general the target session won't become an exact replica. Still, if all you need is to transfer variables you have manually set in the source session, then this method may be enough.

Comment: Is there an easy way to *un*-set variables not in the files declare created? Or even unset all variables first (or that would probably break a few things...)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for directing me to the right community :) What do `2` and `/dev/null` refer to here? I could infer that it's writing the output from 2 to /dev/null but do not understand what each term refer to? Can you please explain me?

Comment: @rm-rfstar `2>/dev/null` is a separate subject, quite a broad one. Answers or comments are not for explaining distinct details, therefore I will keep my answer focused on the original problem. Please do your own research (hint: "shell redirection" is a good phrase to start googling). Later, if something is still unclear to you, ask a *separate* question on Super User.

Comment: @Xen2050 `exec env -i bash --noprofile --norc` – explained in the (edited) answer.

Comment: Amazing answer ! Thanks a ton man ! @KamilMaciorowski :)